# C++ : read csv file with fgetc and separate words on semicolon ";"

Tags: c++, arrays, csv, struct

I have to read in a csv file with 5 fields (int , char[], char[], char[], float) that looks like that :

```
2345678;Meier;Hans;12.10.1985;2.4;      
1234567;Müller;Fritz;17.05.1990;1.9;
```

I have to put the fields in a struct, and then put the struct after one line is complete, into a array of the struct type ...

for the learning effect, we are only allowed to use LOW-LEVEL coding, and only use functions like fgetc, strcpy and no strings, only char[]...
Now I made my algorithm to read the textfile character by character, but I have problems separating them correctly, putting them together again and assigning them to the struct fields correctly. Here is my Code:

```
  #include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct Stud{
        long matrnr;
        char vorname[30];
        char name[30];
        char datum[30];
        float note;
    };

    const int MAX = 30;
    Stud stud;  
    Stud mystud[30]; // <<-- Array of "Stud" type
    //memset((void*)mystud,0,sizeof(mystud) * sizeof(Stud));
    int wordCounter(0);
    int i(0); //thats the charCounter or index
    int studentCounter(0);
    char wort[MAX];
    //int matrnr;
    //char vorname[MAX];
    //char name[MAX];
    //char datum[MAX];
    //float note;


  FILE * pFile;
  int cnr(0); 


  pFile=fopen("studentendaten.txt","r");  
  if (pFile==nullptr) 
  {
      perror ("Fehler beim öffnen der Datei");
  }

  else
  {       
    while (cnr != EOF) 
    {       
        (cnr=fgetc(pFile)) ;


        if ((char)cnr == '\n') {
            mystud[studentCounter] = stud;
            studentCounter++;                       
            continue;           
        }

        if ((char)cnr == ';') { 

            wort[i] = '\0'; 

            switch (wordCounter % 5) {

                case 0:             
                stud.matrnr = atol(wort);
                break;

                case 1:
                strcpy(stud.name, wort);
                break;

                case 2:
                strcpy(stud.vorname, wort);
                break;

                case 3:
                strcpy(stud.datum,wort);
                break;

                case 4:
                stud.note = atof(wort); 
                break;
            }       

            wordCounter++;          
            i = 0;
            continue;
        }

        if (wordCounter %  5 == 0 && (char)cnr != ';') {        
        wort[i] = (char)cnr;
        i++;
        //stud.matrnr = atol(wort);
        }           

        if (wordCounter % 5 == 1) {
            wort[i] =  (char)cnr;
            i++;
        //strcpy(stud.name, wort);
        }

        if (wordCounter % 5 == 2) {
            wort[i] = (char)cnr;
            i++;
            //strcpy(stud.vorname, wort);
        }

        if (wordCounter % 5 == 3) {
            wort[i] = (char)cnr;
            i++;
            //strcpy(stud.datum,wort);
        }

        if (wordCounter % 5 == 4) {
            wort[i] = (char)cnr;
            i++;
            //stud.note = atof(wort);                       
        }

    }   


    fclose (pFile);
}
for (int i(0) ; i <= studentCounter; i++) {
cout <<mystud[i].matrnr << "    " << mystud[i].name << "    " << mystud[i].vorname <<"    " 
<< mystud[i].datum <<"    " << mystud[i].note << endl;
  //printf("%5ld        %5s      %5s     %5s     %5f     \n",mystud[i].matrnr,mystud[i].name,mystud[i].vorname,mystud[i].datum,mystud[i].note);

}

    return 0;
}
```

I am not sure if it has to do with a wrong increment variables, or the fact that I don't put an '\0' at the  end of my wort[] array..and therefore not recognizing the end of my array? And if so, how do I do it without knowing where the end exactly is... ? (I don't know the length of the words..)

EDIT: I updated my code again, the only thing that wonders me is that the LAST LINE IS NOT BEING CORRECTLY PARSED , its showing some rubbish, and I can't see the error in my code...

```
2345678;Meier;Hans;12.10.1985;2.4;      
1234567;Müller;Fritz;17.05.1990;1.9;
8392019;Thomas;Kretschmer;28.3.1920;2.5;
3471144;Mensch;Arbeit;29.2.2013;4.5;
2039482;Test;Test;30.20.2031;2.0;
7584932;Bau;Maschine;02.02.2010;2.3;
2345678;Meier;Hans;12.10.1985;2.4;      
1234567;Müller;Fritz;17.05.1990;1.9;
8392019;Thomas;Kretschmer;28.3.1920;2.5;
3471144;Mensch;Arbeit;29.2.2013;4.5;
2039482;Test;Test;30.20.2031;2.0;
7584932;Bau;Maschine;02.02.2010;2.3;
2345678;Meier;Hans;12.10.1985;2.4;      
1234567;Müller;Fritz;17.05.1990;1.9;
8392019;Thomas;Kretschmer;28.3.1920;2.5;
3471144;Mensch;Arbeit;29.2.2013;4.5;
2039482;Test;Test;30.20.2031;2.0;
7584932;Bau;Maschine;02.02.2010;2.3;
2345678;Meier;Hans;12.10.1985;2.4;      
1234567;Müller;Fritz;17.05.1990;1.9;
8392019;Thomas;Kretschmer;28.3.1920;2.5;
3471144;Mensch;Arbeit;29.2.2013;4.5;
2039482;Test;Test;30.20.2031;2.0;
7584932;Bau;Maschine;02.02.2010;2.3;
```

Comment: One advice: don't use variables like n, i and j.  Instead, use longer words such as wordCounter, wordIndex, and studentCounter.  It will make it a lot more clear when you're debugging what's happening.

Comment: you are confused between `char` (a single character) and `char[]` (an array of characters). You need to copy every character from the input to the output - write your own `stringCopy` function since you are not allowed (presumably) to use `strcpy`.

Comment: It looks like you probably want to put `continue` if it's `'\n'` or `';'`.  Otherwise, you'll copy the separators into the code you're keeping.

Comment: I am allowed to use strcpy ... how can I do it?

Comment: Ah - well see my code example, and make life a little bit simpler for yourself. It is not a "complete solution", but rather a "see if you can get going from here" answer. You learn more that way...

Comment: C++ construcors (where you use the `(0)` notation) and C initializers (where you use the `= { ... } ` notation) are not the same thing. So I take it you are really interested in C++ ? Remove the C tag, then. These are two different languages.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion: use a `case` structure for the parsing, and make yourself a "copyToSemicolon" function: then you can write things like

```
sIndexCount = 0;
char temp[50];
while((cnr=fgetc(pFile)) != EOF) {
  offset = 0;
  for(var = 0; var < 5; var++ {
    switch(var) {
    case 0:
      offset = copyToSemicolon(temp, cnr, offset) + 1;
      stud.matrnr = atoi(temp);
      break;
    case 1:
      offset = copyToSemicolon(mystud[sIndexCount].vorname, cnr, offset) + 1;
      break;
    ... etc
    }
  }
  sIndexCount++;
  if(sIndexCount == 50) break;  // in case the input file is longer than our structure
}
```

And you need a function `copyToSemicolon` that takes two `char*` pointers as inputs, and that copies characters from the second string (starting at `offset`) until it reaches either a semicolon or the end of line - and that returns the offset it reached (last character read).

```
int copyToSemicolon(char* dest, char* source, int offset) {
  while(source[offset] != ';' && source[offset] != '\n') {
    *dest = source[offset++];
    dest++;
  }
  return offset;
}
```

**EDIT** `strtok` method:

```
sIndexCount = 0;
char temp[50];
while((cnr=fgetc(pFile)) != EOF) {
  offset = 0;
  temp = strtok(cnr, ';');
  for(var = 0; var < 5; var++ {
    switch(var) {
    case 0:
      stud.matrnr = atoi(temp);
      break;
    case 1:
      strcpy(mystud[sIndexCount].vorname, strtok(NULL, ';'));
      break;
    ... etc
    case 4:
      mystud[sIndexCount].note = atof(strtok(NULL, '\n'));
    }
  }
  sIndexCount++;
  if(sIndexCount == 50) break;  // in case the input file is longer than our structure
}
```

Comment: hmmm that sounds quite complicated for a very beginner in C++ like me... what are you doing in that lines :  offset = copyToSemicolon(temp, cnr, offset) + 1;
      stud.matrnr = atoi(temp);

Comment: I am actually trying to make it simpler for you. A bit of structure keeps your code clean. Are you allowed to use `strtok`? I thought "no string functions" but maybe I am wrong. I just saw you can use `strcpy`. What is "low level"...

Comment: as far as I know we may only use strcpy, fgetc no string class , just char[], don't know if we may use strtok, u could show me the advantages of it though... :)

Comment: I wrote `copyToSemicolon` for you... it is easier to use (in this instance) than `strtok`.

Comment: hm what is the strtok function doing? in that line:  temp = strtok(cnr, ';'); I mean you are not adding the cnr to the temp[] anywhere nor changing the int cnr into a char... and how does the strtok "remember" the coming cnr and adding them together to a word and splitting it then at a ";" ??

Comment: In the first call, you scan `cnr` for the first semicolon, and pass a pointer to that string to `temp` (actually for this to work, you need `char* temp;` not `char temp[50]);`. And then `strtok` "remembers" the string, and where it got to... so you pass it `NULL` as the first parameter, and it 'keeps going'. It is _exactly_ intended for this application. Look it up!

Comment: Made a critical update... `strtok` returns a pointer to the string you want but it needs to be copied into your structure...

Answer (score 0):

One issue that I am seeing is that your code copies or parses one character at a time, such that when you're reading `2345678;Meier;Hans;12.10.1985;2.4;` you first set `stud.matrnr` to 2, then 23, then 234, then 2345, then 23456, then 234567, then 2345678.  Similarly, for `stud.name`, you first set it to M, then the Me, then to Mei, etc.  I propose to you to think of things in a different way.  I'll give you some pseudocode:

```
while (!eof) {
    get character from file
    if (character isn't ';' and isn't '\n') {
        copy character into buffer (increment buffer index)
    } else if (character is ';') {
        it's the end of a word.  Put it in its place - turn it to an int, copy it, whatever
        reset the buffer
    } else if (character is '\n') {
        it's the end of the last word, and the end of the line.  Handle the last word
        reset the buffer
        copy the structure
    }
}
```

This should make life a lot easier on you.  You're not changing your data nearly as much, and if you need to debug, you can focus on each part on its own.

Generally, in programming, the first step is making sure you can say in your native speaking language what you want to do, then it's easier to translate it to code.  You're close with you implementation, and you can make it work.  Just be sure you can explain what should be happening when you see ';' or '\n'.

Comment: thats a good idea using a buffer, but I am not allowed to use string class... just char[] class... what is the buffer class can u give me an example?

Comment: @user2774480 You already have it.  A buffer is something that holds a value temporarily.  In your case, you're using `wort` as a buffer.  You've already coded all of the pseudocode I gave you; I've simply reordered it to be more efficient (and easier to debug).

Comment: ok I tested my new code with my list, I didnt apply your version yet, I still don't understand why in the last 2 lines of my testfile, the output begins to get weird, and after that, just random rubbish is filled into the array, because it's not reached the maximum array size and it fills up with random stuff from the memory I guess... how can I "close" the array after reaching the end of file (EOF) ??

Comment: @user2774480 Initialize it all to 0.  You should be allowed to use `memset`, it's pretty primitive.  Again, my way is optional.  You don't need it to make it work, but it's (in my opinion) a lot cleaner.

Comment: I did memset(mystud,0,sizeof(mystud)); but there is still something of rubbish left at the end... hm

Comment: @user2774480 sizeof(mystud) isn't entirely what you want.  That will give you 50.  You want `sizeof(mystud) * sizeof(Stud)`, which would give you 50 * 68 on most compilers.  So effectively, you clear 50 bytes, but then you fill them with good data.

Comment: @user2774480 - I would recommend that you count the number of "valid" elements as you fill the array, and then print only the valid elements (rather than the entire array).

Comment: @ScottMermelstein - thanks. I thought OP would automatically be notified of activity. I (almost) never ask questions... But when I do I tend to stalk the page.

Comment: @ScottMermelstein, sizeof(mystud) * sizeof(Stud) didn't work, my program didnt respond anymore after that ;)  I set studentCounter in the for loop for the cout, that worked nice, however my last line was some rubbish although it should be a regular line from the csv file, I dont know what went wrong there...

Comment: @user2774480 Wow.  2 people upvoted my comment, and it was very wrong.  (It's been a long time since I've done pure C).  From what I see now, `sizeof(mystud)` should have worked fine.  Try testing, and print out what the value of `sizeof(mystud)` and `sizeof(mystud) * sizeof(Stud)` each are.  You want the one that ends up with 3400 bytes.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have tagged this as C++, you should consider using `std::getline` for reading the line from the file, the use `std::getline(file, text_before_semicolon, ';')` for parsing the fields.

You could also use `std::istringstream` for converting the textual representation in the text line to internal numeric format.

Comment: thats a good idea, but I'm not sure if we may use std::getline or istringstream...